# Why does ByteBuddy tell me that there is an ambiguity in my interceptor methods when there is only one such method?

Tags: byte-buddy

(Trying to keep this simple.)

I have a (partial) ByteBuddy recipe like this:

```
builder
  .method(someMatcher())
  .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(this.interceptor));
```

I have an "interceptor" class defined like this:

```
private static final class Interceptor {

  private Interceptor() {
    super();
  }

  @RuntimeType
  private final Object doSomething(@This final Proxy<?> proxy,
                                   @SuperCall final Callable<?> callable,
                                   @Origin final String methodSignature) throws Exception {
    final Object proxiedInstance = proxy.getProxiedInstance();
    // TODO: logic
    return callable.call(); // for now
  }

}
```

(The interceptor method needs to be non-`static` for various reasons not important here.)

When I create an instance of this ByteBuddy-defined class and call a simple `public void blork()` method on it, I get:

```
Cannot resolve ambiguous delegation of public void com.foo.TestExplorations$Frob.blork() to net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.MethodDelegationBinder$MethodBinding$Builder$Build@3d101b05 or net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.MethodDelegationBinder$MethodBinding$Builder$Build@1a9efd25
```

How can there be ambiguity when there is only one interceptor?  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Ah; seems to be a visibility issue; changing the interceptor method (`doSomething`) visibility from `private` to default seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Byte Buddy just adds a method call to the instrumented class which needs to be able to see the target class. If it is `private`, it is ignored and Byte Buddy searches further up the hierarchy where it finally consideres the methods of `Object` which are all equally unsuited but therefore an ambiguity exception is thrown instead of an exception that no method could be bound.

Comment: Thanks; I think my confusion resulted from the fact that ambiguity implies I've created two things, not one, and the computer can't decide between them.  Here, I've created no things, and the computer implied that I have created many things.  That was confusing.  Thanks for your answer.